# parsing text of a yes/no query

Tags: artificial-intelligence

I am automating a process which asks questions (via SMS but shouldn't matter) to real people.  The questions have yes/no answers, but the person might respond in a number of ways such as: sure, not at this time, yeah, never or in any other way that they might.  I would like to attempt to parse this text and determine if it was a yes or no answer (of course it might not always be right).

I figured the ideas and concepts to do this might already exist as it seems like a common task for an AI, but don't know what it might be called so I can't find information on how I might implement it.  So my questions is, have algorithms been developed to do this kind of parsing and if so where can I find more information on how to implement them?

Comment: A well-engineered regular expression can solve this problem.

Comment: @BlackBear: either the RE could handle them, or the system could ask the user to repeat the answer, depending on how complicated an RE the OP is willing to handle. LR doesn't magically handle typos either :)

Comment: @larsmans maybe you are right, I'm just over-excited by that machine learning class on coursera ;)

Comment: A regular expression would be tough as there are many words that can mean yes.  I suppose I would need to compile a list of positive or yes words and a list of no words and see if the answer contains any of them.  This is my current thought but I couldn't find already compiled lists of these types of words and I thought it might be a common problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be viewed as a [binary (*yes* or *no*) classification task](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_classification). You could write a rule-based model to classify or a statistics-based model.

A rule-based model would be like `if answer in ["never", "not at this time", "nope"] then answer is "no"`. When spam filters first came out they contained a lot of rules like these.

A statistics-based model would probably be more suitable here, as writing your own rules gets tiresome and does not handle new cases as well.

For this you need to label a [training dataset](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Training_set). After a little preprocessing (like lowercasing all the words, removing punctuation and maybe even a little stemming) you could get a dataset like

```
0 | never in a million years
0 | never
1 | yes sir
1 | yep
1 | yes yes yeah
0 | no way
```

Now you can run classification algorithms like Naive Bayes or Logistic Regression over this set (after you vectorize the words in either binary, which means is the word present or not, word count, which means the term frequency, or a tfidf float, which prevent bias to longer answers and common words) and learn which words more often belong to which class.

In the above example `yes` would be strongly correlated to a positive answer (1) and `never` would be strongly related to a negative answer (0). You could work with n-grams so a `not no` would be treated as a single token in favor of the positive class. This is called the bag-of-words approach.

To combat spelling errors you can add a spellchecker like Aspell to the pre-processing step. You could use a charvectorizer too, so a word like `nno` would be interpreted as `nn` and `no` and you catch errors like `hellyes` and you could trust your users to repeat spelling errors. If 5 users make the spelling error `neve` for the word `never` then the token `neve` will automatically start to count for the negative class (if labeled as such).

You could write these algorithms yourself (Naive Bayes is doable, Paul Graham has wrote a few accessible essays on how to classify spam with Bayes Theorem and nearly every ML library has a tutorial on how to do this) or make use of libraries or programs like Scikit-Learn (MultinomialNB, SGDclassifier, LinearSVC etc.) or Vowpal Wabbit (logistic regression, quantile loss etc.).

Comment: Machine-learned binary classification is both overkill and not smart enough. What if the users enters something entirely incomprehensible? Then the classifier is just going to predict yes or no depending on the bias it's learned from its input. You need three-way classification, and that can be solved very easily with a pair of regular expressions.

Comment: If the user enters something entirely incomprehensible no algorithm or approach is going to divine the correct answer. A classifier will say "I am not sure if this belongs to a positive or a negative class" which is an actionable answer. A regular expression will say "I could not classify this as either positive or negative". Then you do not know if this is due to your regular expression lacking or if the answer is incomprehensible. Machine-learning approaches here will get a better accuracy, like they did when combating spam, where using regular expressions would require constant updates.

Comment: So will ML: you need to keep labeling samples for the accuracy to improve.

Comment: If the accuracy is high enough, you can use classified observations in the training of your model. Unsupervised or semi-supervised learning does not require you to keep labeling samples. Simple: If a classifier deems a new email to be spam with a high certainty, it can use the new (not yet encountered) words from this email to improve its classification. If we stick to your point, that labeling is needed for both, once we have a training set, I can run ML algo's on it and get predictions. You propose writing regular expressions that match your labels? Wouldn't take a while and be error-prone?

Answer (score 0):

Im thinking on top of my head, if you get a response which you dont know if its yes / no, you can keep the answers in a DB like unknown_answers and 2 more tables as affirmative_answers / negative_answers, then in a little backend system, everytime you get a new unknown_answer you qualify them as yes or no, and there the system "learns" about it and with time, you will have a very big and good database of affirmative / negative answers.